# Add recurring index to pandas multi indexed dataframe while keeping the order

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I would like to add a new column to the dataframe belwow with the name new_col that will contain which number of entry it is in the last index (while keeping the order or ordering them so that they are ordered by update time for each sub group). The result should be as below show in new_col.

```
                                             UPDATE_TIME             new_col  
BOOK_NAME BUSINESS_DATE      MEASURE_DEF_ID                  
144       02-NOV-16 12:00:00 PNL            02-NOV-16 05:30:24       1
                                            03-NOV-16 05:30:29       2
                                            04-NOV-16 04:38:46       3
                             RISK           02-NOV-16 09:32:26       1
                                            03-NOV-16 09:31:49       2
                                            03-NOV-16 11:08:17       3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
print (df.set_index('new_col', append=True))
                                                            UPDATE_TIME
BOOK_NAME BUSINESS_DATE      MEASURE_DEF_ID new_col                    
144       02-NOV-16 12:00:00 PNL            1        02-NOV-16 05:30:24
                                            2        03-NOV-16 05:30:29
                                            3        04-NOV-16 04:38:46
                             RISK           1        02-NOV-16 09:32:26
                                            2        03-NOV-16 09:31:49
                                            3        03-NOV-16 11:08:17
```

You need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for creating `Series` for last level of `index`:

```
print (df.set_index(df.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).cumcount() + 1, append=True))
```

Comment: That could work but how can I sort them by update_time for each subgroup first?

Comment: So problem is you need create this column first? I am afraid but i dont understand. Can you explain more?

Comment: Or do you need `df = df.sort_values('UPDATE_TIME')` ? [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Comment: Your solution is fine but what if update_time is not correctly ordered yet? How can I make sure it's ordered as it is shown above by each group?

Comment: sort_values would sort them all, but I just want to sort each PNL and RISK group by itself, so in the above case there would need to be 2 separate sorts.

Comment: `MEASURE_DEF_ID` have only two categories `PNL` and `RISK` ?

Comment: yes but there are many books and many business days and each needs to be sorted separately

Comment: the above answer does not work, as I don't have new_col yet. I want to create this column. I want to create a column which tells me which item in each group was first. The problem is not that I want to convert a column into an index. The problem is that I want to create a new column called new_col which which contains the order of the items.

Comment: yes looks much better now. Will need to give a name to that index so I can reset it. Then group it again so I can calculate the diference in update_time of each element.

Comment: If need new column use `df['new_col'] = df.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).cumcount() + 1`